Linux: How to find CPU socket type via CLI?
using:
Linux terminal CLI (Command Line Interface) ...
What is the command to determine CPU socket type?
using:
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:' 
.
for this computer, expecting an answer like:
LGA 1700 pins
LGA Socket – Land Grid Array Socket
https://pcguide101.com/motherboard/how-to-check-motherboard-socket/
.
No 'LGA' evidence found using commands:
lscpu             |grep -i 'LGA\|socket\|slot'  
lspci -v          |grep -i 'LGA\|socket\|slot'  
x86info -a        |grep -i 'LGA\|socket\|slot'  
hwinfo --cpu      |grep -i 'LGA\|socket\|slot'  
sudo inxi -Fx     |grep -i 'LGA\|socket\|slot'  
sudo dmidecode    |grep -i 'LGA\|socket\|slot'  
cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -i 'LGA\|socket\|slot'  

Linux:  How to find CPU socket type via CLI ?
--

Considering that the socket type is information about the physical characteristics of the CPU, I'm surprised that even dmidecode can provide this information in some cases. The simple fact is that such a software command that can tell you such a thing reliably doesn't exist. The most consistent way: find the CPU model and look it up yourself.

The direct information appears to be available from dmidecode:
sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep Socket

There doesn't seem to be an option to dmidecode to dump everything, you have to ask for specific sections to get more verbose output.
Note that this gives you a socket model number which you may have to look up to get a more verbose description.
Also note that dmidecode seems to be unreliable, and as pointed out in comments, is only as reliable as the manufacturer who coded the answers into the bios.  So use the following less direct methods if you don't get a good answer from dmidecode.
Other less direct methods:
You can get the cpu model with lscpu | grep Model and then look up the cpu model on the vendor's website (or wikipedia) and generally there's only one socket type per model.
You can also approach this from the other direction.
Use sudo dmidecode -t 2 to get the motherboard model (under Product Name) and find the manual for that motherboard and look up what socket type it has.
Note also if you use the -E option with gnu grep, then you don't need the \ characters and your regex is easier to type and a bit more readable.

command
sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep Socket
outputs
Socket Designation: U3E1
still looking for Linux command to show
LGA1700

user10489 > if you use the -E option with gnu grep,
then you don't need the \ characters _ ok
lscpu |grep -i  'LGA\|socket\|slot' becomes
lscpu |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'

Do you get a Upgrade: Socket  line or a Socket Designation: line?

If you don't see the answer you want from the first option, you need to follow up on the indirect options and do the work to get the answer.

I tested on an Amazon EC2 virtual, and it shows "Socket LGA3647"  so dmidecode can see some physical parts of the underlying host.   That was amusing

As @joseph22 discovered, DMI is completely dependent on the OEM/motherboard manufacturer properly encoding the data in the firmware/BIOS.

whenever I need an overview of the computer hardware from the command line i use lshw
in this specific case we can use the class functionality to restrict the output
# lshw -class cpu
*-cpu                     
   description: CPU
   product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5775C CPU @ 3.30GHz
   vendor: Intel Corp.
   physical id: 51
   bus info: cpu@0
   version: 6.71.1
   slot: SOCKET 1150
   size: 3599MHz
   capacity: 3900MHz
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 100MHz
   capabilities: [CUT]


Beware that that information can be... unhelpful. On my desktop, it says slot: U3E1. It's hard to find concrete information on that identifier, but I've found several messages referring LGA1151. However, my CPU is FCLGA1700.

command
sudo lshw -class cpu |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'
outputs
slot: U3E1
still looking for Linux command to show
LGA1700

I get slot: CPU 1 for an LGA 775 slot.

That's the cpu label (as in, cpu1 cpu2) not the model.  Keep looking at other fields.

How to find CPU socket type via CLI ?
sudo dmidecode |grep -iE 'LGA' 
outputs
Upgrade: Socket LGA1700
1700 pins
LGA Socket – Land Grid Array Socket
https://pcguide101.com/motherboard/how-to-check-motherboard-socket/

back story ...
Unsure what changed.
Because days ago command posted by user10489 outputs 1 line
sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep Socket 
outputs
Socket Designation: U3E1

now, days later,
same command outputs 2 lines:
sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep Socket
outputs
Socket Designation: U3E1  
Upgrade: Socket LGA1700  

again, unsure what changed giving above output.

fFR = for Future Readers
sudo dmidecode outputs more information.
sudo dmidecode              |wc -lwc   # Lines Words Characters  
   1112    4174   28115  
  
sudo dmidecode -t processor |wc -lwc   # Lines Words Characters  
     67     261    1902  


As per user10489 > if you use the
-E option with gnu grep, then you don't need the
\ characters ...
example:
lscpu             |grep -i  'LGA\|socket\|slot'  
lscpu             |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  

'LGA' evidence found using:
lscpu             |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  
lspci -v          |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  
x86info -a        |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  
hwinfo --cpu      |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  
sudo inxi -Fx     |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  
sudo dmidecode    |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  
cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -iE 'LGA|socket|slot'  

specifically
sudo dmidecode |grep -iE 'LGA' 
outputs
Upgrade: Socket LGA1700
--
